# Hibernate exception when last_insert_id() called on Apache Derby Embedded

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, derby

I have a trouble with adding record to table in my Spring Boot application with Apache Derby Embedded database and Hibernate.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fm_stations")
public class FmStation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "st_id")
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public FmStation setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    ..........
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface FmStationsRepository extends CrudRepository<FmStation, Integer> {}
```

Processing code:

```
@Autowired
private FmStationsRepository fmStationsRepository;

...............

FmStation fmStation = new FmStation()
                        .setName(splStation[0])
                        .setStationParams(station);
fmStationsRepository.save(fmStation);

...............
```

Properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform        = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql                 = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto       = update
```

I get exception in save method when hibernate running last_insert_id() function. This exception looks like:

```
Hibernate: insert into fm_stations (st_name, st_params) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select last_insert_id()
2017-02-10 16:22:44.151  WARN 8204 --- [       Thread-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 20000, SQLState: 42X01
2017-02-10 16:22:44.151 ERROR 8204 --- [       Thread-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 23.
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select last_insert_id()]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:236)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:219)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.save(Unknown Source)
at by.virkom.skss.ctm.component.thread.DvbStationsScanner.run(DvbStationsScanner.java:51)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:78)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:67)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2855)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3426)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:554)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:539)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:480)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 23.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
... 53 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 23.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 68 more
```

Can somebody help me with this issue?

P.S.: When I try to add row, table is empty.

Comment: You're using the MySQL5Dialect, but your database is not MySQL5, it's Derby. So basically, you're trying to speak chinese with a French guy. It works better if you speak Chinese with chinese guys, and French with French guys.

Comment: Yes you are right. I did forgot this when copying the configuration from another project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong dialect

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

try one of the Derby dialect

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot this when copying the configuration from another project. Thank you.